# Удаление элемента списка в цикле foreach не бросает ConcurrentModificationException, почему?

Tags: java, foreach, коллекции

Допустим, у меня есть некий `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  list.add((int) (Math.random() * 20));
```

И я хочу из него удалить все числа больше 10.

"Правильно" сделать это можно через итератор, получив гарантированный результат.

```
for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); )
    if (iterator.next() > 10)
        iterator.remove();
```

Но на мое удивление, корректно работает и вариант:

```
for (Integer i : list)
    if (i > 10)
        list.remove(i);
```

Несмотря на то, что везде говорится, что любая попытка удаления из коллекции в цикле без использования итератора приводит к `ConcurrentModificationException`.

И, действительно, если будем удалять безусловно, получим как раз `ConcurrentModificationException`

```
for (Integer i : list)
      list.remove(i);
```

Собственно, может кто-нибудь объяснить магию или дать наводку, где можно почитать на эту тему?

Comment: по-моему,  вам просто [повезло](http://ideone.com/FuDKb7) и в списке не оказалось элементов больше 10.

Comment: Никто не гарантирует, что `ConcurrentModificationException` обязательно выкинется. Но никто не гарантирует, что она не выкинется, у меня например данный код выкидывает `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: хотя на списке `1, 22, 3` прекрасно сработает :)

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> сам по себе не сихнронизированный(и это его плюсик) зачем именно Interator вам? remove не гуд да?

Comment: @zRrr надо посмотреть как работает указатель в `foreach`...... в целом, если это самое удаляемое число будет предпоследним в списке, то ошибки не будет....... видимо указатель в начале смещается на позицию вперед, а потом только удаляет элемент

Comment: @АлексейШиманский там, по сути, условие выхода - равенство указателя размеру списка. Цикл завершится, не обработав последний элемент.

Comment: для полноты, в java 8 можно написать `list.removeIf( i -> i > 10 );`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Видимо вам сказочно повезло:

- у вас не было элементов, значение которых было больше 10
- у вас был элемент, значение которого было больше 10, но он был только один и располагался на предпоследнем месте в списке

Давайте рассмотрим работу на более коротком примере.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(22);
list.add(3);
```

Мы добавили три числа. Итак, как работает `foreach`

1. Он получает итератор.
2. Проверяет на наличие следующего элемента `hasNext()`.

   ```
   public boolean hasNext() {
       return cursor != size(); // cursor is zero initially.
   }
   ```
3. Если возвращается `true`, то берет следующий элемент с помощью`next()`.

   ```
   public E next() {
       checkForComodification();
       try {
           E next = get(cursor);
           lastRet = cursor++;
           return next;
       } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
           checkForComodification();
           throw new NoSuchElementException();
       }
   }

   final void checkForComodification() {
       // Initially modCount = expectedModCount (our case 5)
       if (modCount != expectedModCount)
           throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
   }
   ```

Далее повторяются шаги 2 и 3 пока `hasNext()` не вернет `false`.

Если удалить элемент из списка, то его размер уменьшится и `modCount` увеличится.

Если удалить элемент во время итерации, то будет выброшено `ConcurrentModificationException` исключение на строке
`modCount != expectedModCount`.

---

Но что происходит, если удаляется предпоследний элемент?

```
> cursor = 0 size = 3 --> hasNext() успешно и next() тоже без эксепшена
> cursor = 1 size = 3 --> hasNext() успешно и next() тоже без эксепшена
```

Когда мы удалим значение 22, то размер уменьшится до 2.

```
> cursor = 2 size = 2 --> hasNext() не успешно и next() пропускается.
```

В других же случаях будет выброшено `ConcurrentModificationException` из-за `modCount != expectedModCount`.

А в этом единичном случае проверка пройдет на ура..

Вот магия....Или баг....

Comment: Спасибо! Глупо получилось, действительно, ключевой была фраза "у вас не было элементов, значение которых было больше 10". Дело в том, что пример взял из куска кода, в котором между заполнением и удалением было еще разное, где не явным способом уже удалялись все элементы со значением больше 10. Попробовал запустить пример в "чистом" виде и получил заветный ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: @Anton На самом деле информацию о возможности удалить предпоследний элемент тоже мало кто знает...... так что весьма полезно окажется кому-то это всё...... вот еще б как-то вопрос более корректно назвать, чтоб можно было потом по поиску найти...

Answer (score 5):

Да нечего читать на эту тему. В документации ясно сказано, что для удаления элeментов из коллекции нужно использовать итератор.

Тот факт, что в вашем примере вы смогли удалить числа больше 10 обусловлен скорее всего тeм, что там не было таких чисел или было только одно - предпоследнее.
Хотя реалиция `foreach` основана на использовании итератора, но если вы представите что внутри `foreach` обыкновенный `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` то я думаю будет очевидно почему нельзя удалять элементы из массива пока вы его обходите в цикле.

А вообще, используйте Java 8, и забудьте о проблемах :)

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
list.removeIf(e -> e > 10);
```

Comment: `или было только одно - последнее.` а как же предпоследнее?))

Comment: не не не. вот если делать через `foreach` как и пытается ТС, то - предпоследнее, а с `for` - то прокатит только последнее.......тут разница есть.... а т.к. `foreach` использует внутри себя iterator, то сравнивать просто с `for` нет смысла, имхо

Comment: @АлексейШиманский согласен, предпоследнее

Comment: Согласен дважды.