# Чем iterator отличается от цикла for в Java?

Tags: java, итераторы

Объясните, пожалуйста, в каких случаях итератор лучше цикла? Еще мне интересно как в итераторе я могу задать сортировку элементов массива, например, по алфавиту или по конкретной букве.

Comment: сортировка осуществляется [классом Comparator (интерфейсом Comparable)](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/5.6.php), а не итератором

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Итератор не лучше цикла. Итератор — способ перебрать все элементы какой-либо сущности. А цикл не обязательно что-то перебирает. Например, `while (true){}` не перебирает ничего. Цикл для простоты понимания лучше рассматривать, как хождение по кругу. Причем этот круг может вообще намертво замкнуться и цикл станет бесконечным.
Сравним два применения цикла:

Когда вы делаете так

```
ArrayList <String> list = new Arraylist <>();
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)System.out.printl(list [i]);
```

И так

```
ArrayList <String> list = new Arraylist <>();
for (String s : list) System.out.printl(s);
```

На вид происходит то же самое, а на самом деле — это принципиально разный код.
Во втором случае вы используете итератор, просто неявно. Его использует сокращенный цикл `for`.
В первом случае вы используете особенности реализации `ArrayList`, а именно то, что в `ArrayList` есть индексы, по которым можно получить доступ к элементам `ArrayList`.
Здесь итератор, который имплементируется коллекцией, не вызывается, а цикл просто перебирает все натуральные числа от 0 до тех пор, пока это самое натуральное число не станет равным длине коллекции, тогда цикл прерывается.
Посему перебрать, например, коллекцию типа `Set` первым способом вы уже не сможете, ведь индексов у сета нет, а вот вторым без проблем, потому как сет имплементирует итератор.

Исходя из сказанного, становится понятно, что сортировка элементов тут ни при чем. Назначение итератора, как уже было сказано — перебрать все элементы сущности.
Если вам нужна сортировка, то существует другая замечательная штука, называемая компаратор, но сейчас не об этом. Итератор — не средство сортировки. Вы должны понимать, что мы говорим об интерфейсе, имплементировать который могут классы с абсолютно разной логикой. К примеру, коллекция `HashSet` не гарантирует порядок элементов и вы никак не можете их упорядочить в пределах этой коллекции. Соответственно итератор, как интерфейс, невозможно приспособить для таких задач. Сущность, его имплементирующая, может просто не поддерживать сортировку элементов в принципе в виду особенности своей внутренней логики, как HashSet.

И последнее…
Вызывать итератор в явном виде зачастую нецелесообразно и делается это, как правило в одном случае — когда во время итерации вам нужно удалять элементы. У итератора есть методы `hasNext`, `next` и `remove`, которые проверяют наличие следующего элемента, получают следующий элемент и удаляют элемент соотвественно. Попытка удаления элемента при итерации с помощью цикла приведет к исключению. Причем исключение будет брошено даже, если вы используете сокращенный цикл типа `for (String s : list)`. Происходит это потому что, хотя этот цикл неявно и использует итератор, у вас нет к нему доступа. Соответственно, единственный доступный вам способ удалить элементы — вызывать метод `remove` у коллекции `list`, что приведет к исключению, ведь для удаления элементов во время итерации по ней нужно вызывать метод `remove` не у коллекции `list`, а у самого итератора, к которому, как уже было сказано, у вас в любом из циклов доступа нет.

И еще. В предыдущем абзаце сказано что итератор, как правило, вызывается в одном случае. На самом деле не в одном. Просто зачастую он вызывается именно для указанного случая. А вот остальные случаи вам придется изучить самостоятельно, так как их назначение не столь тривиально, чтобы объяснить это в таком контексте. Речь идет, например, о том, что у одного объекта может быть вызвано несколько итераторов, которым задана разная логика работы. Но это придет со временем.

Comment: По поводу удаления - не совсем так. В обычном цикле при удалении, нпример, из ArrayList-a, не будет никакого исключения, но и результат будет неожиданным - удалятся элементы через один, т.к. в цикле будет изменяться размер листа, от которого зависит к-во итераций цикла.

Comment: Вот тут хорошо описаны разные неочевидные приколы на эту тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540292/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5-foreach-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-concurrentmodificationexcept

Comment: Смотря в каком цикле. Этот бросит исключение for (String s : list) list.remove(s), а этот for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) list.remove(list.get(i)); даст непредсказуемый результат. В любом случае это некорректное решение.

Comment: Но если удаляемый элемент будет единственным и стоять на предпоследнем месте - не бросит )))

Comment: Ага, если коллекция будет пуста, тоже не бросит )))

Comment: Я бы выделил из всего этого главную мысль: 1. Не использовать цикл for(;;), если в нем изменяется коллекция. 2. Если хочется юзать цикл в стиле foreach, нужно понимать, что этот вид цикла вызывает next() в конце, а используя iterator() мы делаем это вначале.

Answer (score 1):

Цикл *enhanced for* при компиляции в байт-код превращается в *iterator*:

Исходный код **Test.java**

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : list) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Декомпилированный класс **Test.class**

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
Iterator var2 = list.iterator();

while(var2.hasNext()) {
    String s = (String)var2.next();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

---

Цикл с *iterator* после компиляции выглядит также:

Исходный код **Test.java**

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator iterator = list.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String s = (String) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Декомпилированный класс **Test.class**

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
Iterator iterator = list.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    String s = (String)iterator.next();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```