# Как работает цикл foreach в Java?

Tags: java, foreach, java-faq

Есть коллекция и цикл `foreach`:

```
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
//add "monkey", "donkey", "skeleton key" to someList

for(String item : someList) 
  System.out.println(item);
```

Как выглядит цикл `for`, эквивалентный циклу `foreach` выше? Как работает цикл `foreach` внутри? В чем отличия циклов `for` и `foreach`?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Цикл `foreach` - это синтаксический сахар. Внешне прежде всего отличается от `for` отсутствием явного счетчика. [Единственное практическое различие](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22114571/7150209) между ними заключается в том, что в случае индексируемых объектов у вас нет доступа к индексу.

Цикл `foreach` позволяет выполнять итерации по двум типам объектов:

- `T[] //массивы любого типа`
- Объекты, реализующие [интерфейс `Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

### Цикл `for`, работающий с объектами `Iterable`

Код из вопроса

```
for(String item : someList) 
      System.out.println(item);
```

равен коду ниже

```
for (Iterator<E> i = someIterable.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    String item = i.next();
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Этот код работает для любого объекта, реализующего [интерфейс `Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

---

В цикле `foreach` [нельзя использовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540292/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5-foreach-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-concurrentmodificationexcept) метод `remove(index)`. Вместо этого следует использовать `iterator.remove()`. Пример:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); )
    if (iterator.next() > 10)
        iterator.remove();
```

---

Если писать `for` без использования итератора, то вот примерная реализация `foreach`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
  System.out.println(list.get(i));
```

---

### Циклы `foreach` и `for`, работающие с массивами

```
String[] fruits = new String[] { "Orange", "Apple", "Pear", "Strawberry" };

for (String fruit : fruits) {
    // fruit is an element of the `fruits` array.
}
```

по сути эквивалентно

```
for (int i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    String fruit = fruits[i];
    // fruit is an element of the `fruits` array.
}
```

---

### `foreach` против `for` - производительность

При доступе к коллекции, `foreach` [значительно быстрее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22114571/7150209), чем `for`. Однако при доступе к массивам - по крайней мере с массивами примитивов и оболочек - доступ через индексы(т.е. используя `for`) быстрее.

Также при вложенных циклах `foreach` [наблюдаются проблемы с производительностью](https://habr.com/ru/post/164177/) из-за создания большого количество объектов `Iterator`.

---

В Java 8 представили потоки, которые в целом работают лучше.
(хоть эта информация напрямую и не относится к вопросу, но это может быть полезно)

Для работы с коллекций:

```
someList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Для работы с массивом:

```
Arrays.stream(someArray).forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

[Документация Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) по `foreach`.

---

### UPD: Измерение производительности на JDK9

(не стоит серьезно его оценивать, т.к. мне не кажется, что я все правильно измерил)

Для замера производительности я использовал код из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2403921/7150209) вопроса:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getTime());
}

private static void testMethod() {
    //Код, время выполнения которого нужно узнать
}

/**
 * Метод для измерения времени выполнения метода testMethod
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/2404378/7150209
 */
private static double getTime() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++) { //прогрев JVM
        testMethod();
    }
    int count = 1000; //первоначальное кол-во повтора выполнения testMethod

    while(true) {
        long begin =  System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++)
            testMethod();

        long end = System.nanoTime();

        if ((end - begin) < 1000000000) { //Прогон тестов пока суммарное выполнения count раз
            count *= 100000;              //testMethod`a не будет равно несколько секунд
            continue;
        }

        return (double)(end - begin) / count;
    }
}
```

Как работает метод `getTime()` - в цикле for метод с тестируемым кодом запускается `count` раз. Перед началом запусков засекается время, после всех запусков из конечного времени вычитается начальное - получается время запуска `count` раз тестового метода. После этого время делится на count - получается усредненное время одного запуска тестового метода. Если время запуска count раз тестового метода < 10 секунд, то count увеличивается, и замер происходит заново.

В тестовом методе в циклах `for` и `foreach` я использовал:
`переменная = list.get(i)`/`array[i]` для `for` и `переменная = i;` `для foreach`.

В лямбде я использовал `Arrays.stream(array).map(l -> l+1).collect(Collectors.toList());`  и `list.stream().map(l -> l+1).collect(Collectors.toList())`, т.е. изменение элементов коллекции и создание новой коллекции, поэтому выполнение лямбд заняло больше времени.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице видно, что выполнение в лямбде заняло примерно одинаковое время для коллекций и массивов. Время выполнения кода с массивом примерно в 1.5 раза быстрее, чем с коллекцией. Время выполнения цикла `for` и `foreach` для всех одинаковое.

P.S. Пример код `for` и `foreach` для коллекции(n - просто переменная):

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
   n = list.get(i);
```

и

```
for(int i : list)
  n = i;
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо привести замеры производительности на разных версиях jvm (:

Comment: @Suvitruf хорошая идея, проведу, но позже

Comment: С производительностью [есть тонкости](https://habr.com/ru/post/164177/).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ещё актуально?

Comment: @Suvitruf проверил сейчас на 11-й, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev =/

Comment: @AntonSorokin замеры лучше производить с помощью [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Comment: Качественно! Плюсую! Спасибо за перевод!

Comment: @L.F.C. спасибо ^^