# Как удалить последовательность двух элементов из массива или листа?

Tags: java, массивы, list, delete

Как удалить два последовательно идущих элемента из массива или листа?

Есть массив:

```java
String[] array = {"ПЕРВЫЙ", "ВТОРОЙ", "ВТОРОЙ", "ТРЕТИЙ", "ЧЕТВЕРТЫЙ",
        "ПЕРВЫЙ", "ВТОРОЙ", "ПЕРВЫЙ", "ВТОРОЙ", "ПЕРВЫЙ", "ЧЕТВЕРТЫЙ"};
```

Нужно удалить два последовательно идущих элемента:

```
"ПЕРВЫЙ", "ВТОРОЙ"
```

После удаления массив должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
[ВТОРОЙ, ТРЕТИЙ, ЧЕТВЕРТЫЙ, ПЕРВЫЙ, ЧЕТВЕРТЫЙ]
```

Мой код:

```java
String[] s1 = new String[arr.length];

String n = "ПЕРВЫЙ";
String s = "ВТОРОЙ";
String w = "ТРЕТИЙ";
String e = "ЧЕТВЕРТЫЙ";

// Два последовательно идущих элемента найти удалось и элемент,
// следующих за ними. Вопрос в том, как их теперь удалить из листа,
// или скопировать массив в другой массив без этих элементов?

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].equals(n) && arr[i + 1].equals(s)) {
        System.out.println(arr[i + 2]);
    }
}
```

Как удалить два последовательно идущих элемента из массива или листа?

Comment: а в чём проблема сейчас с удалением?

Comment: в джаве массив не динамический, т.е. его размер определяется при создании и не может быть изменен. посему единственное, что можно сделать - создать новый массив

Answer (score 1):

Вам стоит сделать цикл в обратном направлении, от конца к началу, потому что в ином случае при удалении элементов массива непосредственно в цикле может привести к `ConcurrentModificationException`, хотя в редких случаях [волшебно этого может не произойти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/540292/191482) или произойти некорректное удаление, т.к. индексы элементов после удаления смещаются.

В целом можно сделать так:

```
String[] arr = {"ПЕРВЫЙ", "ВТОРОЙ", "ВТОРОЙ", "ТРЕТИЙ", "ЧЕТВЕРТЫЙ",
"ПЕРВЫЙ", "ВТОРОЙ", "ПЕРВЫЙ", "ВТОРОЙ", "ПЕРВЫЙ", "ЧЕТВЕРТЫЙ"};
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));

String n = "ПЕРВЫЙ";
String s = "ВТОРОЙ";
String w = "ТРЕТИЙ";
String e = "ЧЕТВЕРТЫЙ";

for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (list.get(i).equals(s) && list.get(i - 1).equals(n)) {
       list.remove(i);
       list.remove(i);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Здесь два раза вызывается `list.remove(i);`, а не `list.remove(i); list.remove(i - 1);` именно потому, что после вызова первый раз `list.remove(i);` индексы списка пересчитываются и тот, что был на месте `i - 1` перейдёт на индекс `i`

---

С массивами всё сложнее. Удалить непосредственно из массива нельзя без последствий. Нужно каждый раз делать копию массива с уменьшенным количеством элементов, в который в цикле надо будет скопировать все элементы предыдущего, за исключением элемента, расположенного на указанной позиции в статром массиве

Comment: `i > 0;` *(2 символа нужно)*

Comment: я думал что вы не вернётесь

Comment: @Danis тоже так думал) Но пока я добрый.... :D

Comment: почему вы решили уйди и так резко вернуться.(В профиле напишите `I am back`)

Comment: опять пропал.... жду через 3 года

Answer (score 0):

Если у тебя ArrayList, например, то используется метод remove().

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("First");
list.add("Second");
list.remove(0);

for(String v : list)
   System.out.println(v);
//output: Second
```

А если массив, то удалить не получится. Или копировать в новый массив, или "удаленным элементам" присвоить значение null, но это может привести к ошибкам. В этом случае больше всего подойдет метод System.arraycopy().