# Не понимаю принцип работы ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, исключения, итераторы

В статье https://dev64.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/how-to-deal-with-concurrent-modification-exception/, в качестве примера возникновения `ConcurrentModificationException` приводится код:

```
@Test(expected = ConcurrentModificationException.class)
public void testForEachFail() {
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("a", "a");
    map.put("b", "b");
 
    for(String key:map.keySet()) {
        map.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Я скопировал код в среду разработки и `ConcurrentModificationException` там и правда возникает, но я никак не могу понять, почему

Comment: Цитата по вашей ссылке: `Название ConcurrentModificationException многих вводит в заблуждение. При слове Concurrent первое что приходит на ум — многотредность. Однако, данное исключение относится вовсе не к многотредности. Исключение может происходить при работе с коллекциями при обычной однотредной работе. 

ConcurrentModificationException возникает когда коллекция модифицируется «одновременно» с проходом по коллекции итератором любыми средствами кроме самого итератора. `

Comment: А ещё бывает так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/540292/191482